# When updating mysql table row, current_time_stamp updates as well

Tags: mysql

I have a column `date_created` with `current_time_stamp` on to store the date the row was created.
But whenever I apply an `UPDATE` to the row, the `date_created` gets refreshed as well even if I'm not applying any data to that column.

How can I prevent this?

Here is the code where I apply the `UPDATE`:

```
$query = "UPDATE `templates` SET `categoria_id`='$categoria', `title`='$title', `image`='$image', `code`='$code', `date_updated`='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' WHERE `id`='{$id}' LIMIT 1";
if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    echo "up_success";
}
else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, the column has the current timestamp for its default value and is automatically updated to the current timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

With neither DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP nor ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, **it is the same as specifying both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   ts TIMESTAMP
);
```

With a DEFAULT clause but no ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clause, the column has the given default value and is **not automatically updated** to the current timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you. I removed the ` ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and leaved just `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like when the table was created the field was initialized for automatic updating.  Something like the following.

```
CREATE TABLE templates (
   date_created TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A column with type current_timestamp automatically updates every time you apply a successful update to the row.

You are better off renaming date_created to date_updated, and creating a new column with type int(to store unix timestamp generated by time() in php upon creation) or one of the datetime/date/time types.

Answer (score 0):

For the table creation use the following construct. If no default is specified, the timestamp get updated for update of any column as well.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html)